# How to check if a key exists in the payload and use that in a choice condition

Tags: mule, dataweave

I want to check if a key exists in the first element(object) of the array.

When I write the following:

```
flowVars.payloadStored[0].data!=null
```

inside the when condition of choice, I am getting the following error:

Execution of the expression 'flowVars.payloadStored[0].data!=null' failed. -> [Error: null pointer: flowVars.payloadStored[0].data],[Near : {... flowVars.payloadStored[0].data ....}],       ^,[Line: 1, Column: 1] -> ",

Even when trying

```
 flowVars.payloadStored[0].['data']!=null
```

I am still getting an error:

```
[Error: unterminated string literal],[Near : {... flowVars.payloadStored[0].['data']!=null ....}],                                               ^,[Line: 1, Column: 35]"
```

Any clues, how to do that?

Comment: This is not a DataWeave error looks more like mel exception

Comment: @machaval what do you mean? How to resolve it?

Comment: What you shared is a single expression but without the message processor in which it is used, nor the actual payload. It is difficult to understand the issue without more context. I understand from machaval comment that this is not an error usually thrown by DataWeave, so it has to be an error in a MEL expression (Mule Expression Language). It is only DataWeave if it is in a Transform processor. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tempting to do all mapping in one line but in reality you are doing chain of references. You should be sure that each link in the chain does exist.

Based on the message I guess that payloadStored may not exist or it is not an array or it has no elements in the array. To refer first element in the array you should be sure all is true. So, right DW transformation is not elegant but bulletproof should look like this to be sure you will not have null pointer exception:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    data: flowVars.payloadStored[0].['data']
} when flowVars.payloadStored is :array and sizeOf (flowVars.payloadStored) > 0
otherwise
{
    data: "Not Available"
}
```

So your logic should look like this:

```
flowVars.payloadStored is :array and sizeOf (flowVars.payloadStored) > 0 and flowVars.payloadStored[0].['data']!=null
```

Example is here https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/DoubleAndTripleCheckTheInput.html

Comment: Thanks Alex, you really pointed to the issue. I resolved it as you suggested. I added a dw transform before the choice to get a variable which is true if the key exists and is false when the key does not exist. Also, I did not save the payload as java. I just used the payload which is already in json format and looked if it has data element like this: "payload.data?" and saved it to a boolean variable. Then in the choice I just checked the boolean variable.

Comment: Glad it helped.